# Create Dynamic TFS Query in SharePoint Portal

Tags: sharepoint, backlog

We have recently moved our project over to TFS 2010 for CM control and issue tracking.  For the most part we have been happy with the move.  However, we have found that we need a way to allow users (notably our help desk) to write dynamic queries against our Product Backlog.  The `Query Results Web Part` works fine for displaying information like Outstanding Work Items and Recent Issues, but our users need the ability to query for specific information that can change from support call to support call.  Is there a way to allow a user to create a custom, dynamic query in TFS?  If not are there any 3rd party tools that integrate with SharePoint that would allow this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use the `Page Viewer Web Part` to embed the actual query form from the Team Web Access to the Project Portal.  Everything seems to work great when doing that.  The only downside is you get a 'Nag Dialog' whenever you leave the page.

Answer (score 1):

TFS 2010 has a web based user interface called Web Access. Users can create and view their own queries from there with the queries part of te app;  they can also search for work items by words contained in their titles

By default, there is typically a link on the upper-left to it from the SharePoint site that TFS 2010 creates.  If the link is not there you can access it directly its (default) URL:  [http://address-of-your-TFS-server:8080/tfs/web]

Comment: I'd prefer not to force our guys to have to bounce around between 2 sites.  If there was some way to pull that functionality into the Project Portal, then it would solve our problems.